# how to create and use calender filter in Power BI

Tags: filter, calendar, powerbi

I am working on a power BI report where I need to create a calendar type filter. The filter needs to use a condition as this needs to compare two columns of a report. if a user select the date from calendar, the report should return the data for "selected date>=adddate and selected date<=drop date"

I am aware of adding the date filter using the slicer. but the filter will not be a calendar and also we cannot add the condition I have mentioned above

I need to add a new filter as Report date(calendar type). When user select any date from the calendar, result should be matching with the condition for two columns in the report "selected date>=adddate and selected date<=drop date". Please help me with the step by step process as I am very new to Power BI. Attached the view of my report[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: your question in unclear

Comment: Did you try the solution I proposed in your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461892/replicating-the-tableau-report-into-power-bi/57463216#57463216

Comment: @JelleHoekstra I could not understand completely on your solution may be because I am just beginner. I have created a new table using calendar function with date range of '2000-1-1' to '2019-07-31'.but I could not use create a measure using the query you have provided as I am getting syntax error.could you please elaborate on how to create this filter?

Comment: The first step you did is correct. What does the error refer to? It doesn't give a syntax error on a replicated dataset on my machine. Make sure it refers to the right tables and columns, the syntax I used is generic meaning that in Table[column] you should replace the Table with your table name and the column with your column name.  Also note that I use the semicolon as argument separator in my formulas. For more info check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dax-syntax-reference

Comment: @jelle I have attached the screenshot of the table I created, query used and the error message

Comment: Replace Investments with Query1 and as for the columns replace adddate by AddDate and dropdate by DropDate. When typing try to familiarize yourself with the auto-completion. Also really have a look at the link I sent you in the previous comment and try understanding the functions I used. These errors are one of the first things you should be able to recognize and fix yourself when you want to improve your DAX.

Comment: I have corrected the query and measure is created successfully. when I use the measure in visual filter of the matrix and filters for value 1, it is not showing any result.But when I use the condition in sql, it is giving records. please advise. I have attached screenshot to the question

Comment: It releia on the fact that you the Parameter[Date] field to your report as a slicer. As long as you haven't selected a date, it by default takes the smallest date in your calendar table. For this date it probably means there are no records matching the condition. Drag the date field from the parameter table to your report, select it to be a slicer visual and change it into drop down. As soon as you select a date records should start showing.

Comment: even if I pull the parameter date to slicer visual and select the date, it not showing any result

Comment: Can you share the pbix of your report?

Comment: @JelleHoekstra   https://www.dropbox.com/s/55fk04c99sp89kv/NP%20Weighting%20-%20Monthly%20Customer%20Numbers.pbix?dl=0

Comment: The measure I mentioned was designed to determine on row level whether a row has to be in or excluded. This works for a visual that displays all the rows but not the one your are making I see. A simple change is needed, change the 'is' 1 into 'is equal to or greater than' 1. In your visual the Included measure gets aggregated and counts the rows per included in each row you display. This evaluated in your visual basically gives you the filtered Customer Count value. I would rename it and use it instead of your current Customer Count column.