# how to group the values in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, grouping, tableau-api

I am trying to create a power bi replicating the tableau report. In tableau, it automatically group the values when we place the columns in rows pane. But in Power BI, I am not able to group the exact same way of tableau report. Please help me how to group the values in report pane of power bi.

I have tried table and matrix visualization but I am not getting the same view like tableau

Need to create the same visuals like tableau report. Attached images[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461892/replicating-the-tableau-report-into-power-bi/57463216#57463216), there is no exact visual copy of the Tableau visual you show for PowerBI. Instead, it offers the matrix visual where indentation is used to show groups. This, for instance, allows for a nice presentation of subtotals in your visual, something Tableau does differently. If you are really keen on getting the visual appeal closer alike, try changing the indentation under Formatting Options > Row Headers > Stepped layout indentation. That's the closest you are going to get given the current constraints of Power BI.