# How to show each date in a column just once (like Tableau does)?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following table in Power BI Desktop table visualization:

[image]

I don't like that the same dates are repeated over many rows, and would like to show each day just once. Here's what I mean, this is made with Tableau:

[image]

How can I do this in Power BI? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [how to group the values in power bi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57522822/how-to-group-the-values-in-power-bi). It's not as pretty, but it works.

In short:

1: changed the visualization from Table to Matrix

2: moved both the date and the middle column to the "Rows" field of the Matrix